# java exception with Scanner class

Tags: java, variables, object, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a simple calculator 
I asked the user to enter the first number then the second and the operation that is a character (ie : +,-,*,/) but i get an exception when using the same object on  Scanner class 
however when I create a new object it works !!

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in) ; 
    int a , b,res ; 
    char c ; 
    a=0 ; 
    b=0 ; 

    System.out.print("Entrer the frst num ") ;
    a = sc.nextInt() ; 
    System.out.print("entre the second : ") ; 
    b= sc.nextInt() ; 
    System.out.print("the operation plz  ") ; 
    c = sc.nextLine().charAt(0) ;
```

In this case i get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at javatut.tut.main(tut.java:21)
```

but it work when i change :

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in) ; 
 Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    int a , b,res ; 
    char c ; 
    a=0 ; 
    b=0 ; 

    System.out.print("Entrer the frst num ") ;
    a = sc.nextInt() ; 
    System.out.print("entre the second : ") ; 
    b= sc.nextInt() ; 
    System.out.print("the operation plz  ") ; 
    c = sc2.nextLine().charAt(0) ;
```

Why ??

Comment: Asked like a zillion times before.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `sc.nextLine()` after reading the second int. This would consume the newline that follows that int, which would allow the next `sc.nextLine ()` to get the correct input, instead of the empty line it currently gets.